# "Cache-Control: only-if-cached" fails when offline even if response is cached

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, caching, xmlhttprequest, cache-control

I'm developing a web-view based mobile app, and an express.js based backend. Technically, it boils down to an embedded chrome browser and a HTTP endpoint.

In my app, I have a dashboard, and I'd like it to behave this way:

1. Fetch latest data from server (the server always responds with `200 OK` with payload and a `Last-Modified` header, or a `304 Not Modified` and no content)

   - if browser doesn't have the response cached yet - do a normal request with `Cache-Control: max-age=0`
   - otherwise - always do a conditional request with `If-Modified-Since` header
2. If offline / network error - fall back to browser cache

   - do a `Cache-Control: only-if-cached` request, which is supposed to either yield the cached response or fail if none found.

**The problem is that, when the server is down, the fallback request with `Cache-Control: only-if-cached` always fails.** In particular, it fails even if the browser has the response cached (I know it has it cached, because first I get a `200 OK`, and on the second request it yields the response content even upon receiving a `304 Not Modified` - which has no content). So why it fails, then? Or how should I structure the cache-related headers so it works as described?

I'm running:

- Chrome WebView v54
- github/fetch polyfill (but it shouldn't really matter, as I'm operating on bare HTTP headers)
- express.js 4.14.0 with ETags disabled

Other notes: I could probably use service workers so that the dashboard works offline, but the same functionality should be feasible with plain HTTP headers and browser cache, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be possible with HTTP's defined caching behaviour, but only if the browser supports the specification.

In Chromium's source, `only-if-cached` only seems to appear in third-party modules ([`only-if-cached` `package:chromium`](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=only-if-cached&sq=package:chromium&type=cs)). This suggests that the header may not be supported by Chrome.